# Tab Panel behaviour breaks when something is added to Tab Bar Dynamically

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I tried adding this.callParent(arguments) to the tab panel's initialize event
as suggested by http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?234909-tab-panel-doesn-t-switch-between-tabs-when-added-dynamically but I get:

```
Uncaught Error: this.callParent() was called but there's no such method (doFire) found in the parent class (Ext.Base).
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

My controller follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            mytabpanel: '#mytabpanel'
        }
    },

    init: function(application) {

        this.control({
            mytabpanel: {
                initialize: function(component, options){
                    var bar = component.getTabBar();

                    bar.insert(0, { flex:1, xtype:'toolbar', title: '' });

                    bar.insert(bar.getItems().length, 
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        flex: 1,
                        title: '',
                        items: [
                        {
                            xtype : 'button',
                            docked: 'right',
                            ui: 'round',
                            iconCls: 'info',
                            iconMask: true,
                            handler: function(){                       
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    });
                    this.callParent(arguments);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My view follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    config: {
        id: 'mytabpanel',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Tab 1',
                iconCls: 'info',
                html: 'tab 1'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Tab 2',
                iconCls: 'info',
                html: 'tab 2'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Tab 3',
                iconCls: 'info',
                html: 'tab 3'
            }
        ],
        tabBar: {
            docked: 'bottom'
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT Sunday, 30 December 6:57 a.m (GMT - 4:00)**

From searching the web I now believe that because I am overriding initialize then I need to call the superclass' initialize method so that its code will be executed as well.  As pointed out by user1479606 calling this.callParent will never work.  So, the question becomes: How do I call the superclass' initialize method?

Answer (score 0):

I think your application won't work in your case because you should use `this.callParent(arguments)` in your view not your controller otherwise your parent class will always be `Ext.Base`.

For easier to understand and better approach, why don't you follow the Sencha Touch 2 convention like this:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        mytabpanel: '#mytabpanel'
    }

    control: {
        mytabpanel: {
            initialize: 'domytabpanel'
        }
    }
},

domytabpanel: function(component, options) {
    var bar = component.getTabBar();

    bar.insert(0, {
        flex:1, 
        xtype:'toolbar', 
        title: ''
    });

    bar.insert(bar.getItems().length, 
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        flex: 1,
        title: '',
        items: [
        {
            xtype : 'button',
            docked: 'right',
            ui: 'round',
            iconCls: 'info',
            iconMask: true,
            handler: function(){                       
            }
        }
        ]
    });
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I tried your approach, and, while it is easier to understand it also exhibits the problem of a broken tab bar after the dynamic addition of the button and the toolbar.  When I click on a tab after the insertion, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setActive'" and the behaviour of all three tabs in the tab bar is broken. That was the problem I was aiming to solve by calling callParent.

Comment: Change your insert index to three since your tabbar already has 3 items `bar.insert(3, {....})`